# C#: Code works in one class but not in another

Tags: c#

***The solution was to simply make the list static.***

I have code in a class, A. In class A I have a button that runs code to add an object to a list in class B.

In class A I then have another button to open a different form, class C. In class C i have a button that runs the exact same code that the button in class A runs, but the object only gets added to the list when i click the button in class A, the button in class C does not seem to do anything

Class A also contains a ListBox that shows the contents of the list in class B, although I do not think that affects the problem.

Class A:

```
classB manager = new classB();

private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Contact cnt = new Contact();

     manager.AddToList(cnt);
}

private void btnOpenFormC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    classC newForm= new classC();
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Class B:

```
public List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();

public void AddToList(Contact inData)
{
    Customer cm = new Customer();
    cm.Contact = inData;
    cm.Id = GetId();

    CustomerList.Add(cm);
}
```

Class C:

```
classB manager = new classB();

 private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Contact cnt = new Contact();

     manager.AddToList(cnt);
 }
```

So my question is: How do I make it so that I can add objects to the list from both class A and C?

Comment: As posted your code has two instances of `ClassB`, one used by `ClassA` and one used by `ClassC`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How to I use the same instance in both class A and  C?

Comment: If it **literally** does nothing when you click, make sure the event is wired up.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I know that the code runs! I put a Console.Beep(); in there while testing :) @TyCobb

Comment: @Odert there's several ways, you could search for `Singleton` pattern or keep a shared instance. The simplest thing to do could be to make the `CustomerList` `static` then `ClassA` and `ClassC` would operate on the same list while still retaining separate instances of `ClassB`

Comment: I agree with @JSteward's suggestion about the static CustomerList

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now that I made the list static! :) @JSteward

Comment: A static list is a horrible solution. What if you want to use two different instances of `ClassA` with different contents? Use the `manager` of `ClassA` in `ClassC` by simply giving to its constructor at instantiation (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solve in multiple ways

**1st way** - Singleton

Class A

```
var manager = ClassB.Instance;

private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    manager.AddToList(cnt);
}
```

Class B

```
public class ClassB {
    private static ClassB _Instance;

    public static ClassB Instance {
        get {
            if(_Instance==null) _Instance = new ClassB();
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    public List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();

    public void AddToList(Contact inData)
    {
        Customer cm = new Customer();
        cm.Contact = inData;
        cm.Id = GetId();

        CustomerList.Add(cm);
    }
}
```

Class C

```
var manager = ClassB.Instance;

private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    manager.AddToList(cnt);
}
```

---

**2nd way** - Static Customer List

Class A

```
var manager = new ClassB();

private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    manager.AddToList(cnt);
}
```

Class B

```
public class ClassB {
    public static List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();

    public void AddToList(Contact inData)
    {
        Customer cm = new Customer();
        cm.Contact = inData;
        cm.Id = GetId();

        CustomerList.Add(cm);
    }
}
```

Class C

```
var manager = new ClassB();

private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Contact cnt = new Contact();
    manager.AddToList(cnt);
}
```

Personally i would prefer the **1st way** as new instance might consume extra memory allocation. Hope this can help you.

Comment: It is not necessary to use singletons or static variables for such a task, just give the same instance of a `ClassB` to the instances of `ClassA` and `ClassC`. This can be done by constructor parameter or as public property of the consuming classes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I assume `ClassA` and `ClassC` are forms?

In the button click handler to open a `ClassC` form, just put the `manager` member to the constructor of `ClassC`:

ClassA:

```
public class ClassA : Form
{
    private classB manager = new classB();

    ...

    private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Contact cnt = new Contact();

        manager.AddToList(cnt);
    }

    private void btnOpenFormC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassC newForm= new ClassC(manager);
        newForm.Show();
    }
}
```

ClassC:

```
public class ClassC : Form
{
     private ClassB manager;

     public ClassC(ClassB manager)
     {
          this.manager = manager;
          ...
     }

     ...

    private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Contact cnt = new Contact();

        manager.AddToList(cnt);
    }
}
```